# How to delete history items from Redmine issue

Tags: redmine

At the bottom of each issue page there is a History of changes. Some of those are autogenerated by external tools, or by a user that made a mistake, so it would be useful to be able to delete them. Is this possible?

I tried in the standard form and also in the editable form after clicking "Update". I also tried with History updates made with my own user

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am used to do this from the database backend, there's a table which can be edited/emptied. If that helps in your use case.

PA

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you need to truncate the following tables: journals, journal_details. This way you will not destroy any other content. Just do not delete the tables.
PA